# Enable to get the nextInvoiceTotalAmount from SoftLayer_account object

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I cannot get the nextInvoiceTotalAmount from the SoftLayer_Account object
using SoftLayer Rest API

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getObject.json?objectMask=mask[id,nextInvoiceTotalAmount,openTicketCount,openTicketsWaitingOnCustomerCount]
```

Could you let me know how can I get the attribute of current balance, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to this attribute requires the use of Legacy object mask in your request, for current balance the request should add "**balance**" property in the mask, try this improved request:

**UPDATED** to retrieve current balance and next invoice amount.

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getObject?objectMask=id;nextInvoiceTotalAmount;openTicketCount;openTicketsWaitingOnCustomerCount;balance
```

Don't forget to replace **[username]**, and **[apiKey]** with valid credentials.

Currently the portal is using SoftLayer_Account::getNextInvoiceTotalAmount method to retrieve only that specific attribute, try this:

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getNextInvoiceTotalAmount
```

Fore more information please see below:

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/softlayer_account/getnextinvoicetotalamount

https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Legacy-Object-Masks